Why does the UFC have an upper limit of weight?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UFC_champions#Men's_championship_history -> The highest men's division is Heavyweight which has an upper limit of 120kg
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UFC_champions#Women's_Bantamweight_Championship -> The highest women's division is Bantamweight which has an upper limit of 61kg

This is surprising for me, typically the highest weight division should have no upper limit on weight, at least this is the case with boxing?
Women's upper limit of 61kg is especially surprising, I get it women are typically lighter than men, but still 61kg seems to be a pretty low upper limit?
What if a heavier fighter appears? They are not allowed to contest for a title?

will try find supporting resources in the coming days.
UFC is licensed by the state commissions to have fights under those weight classes that it doesn't carry (at least some of them). It's a business decision they've made till now to not carry some of those weight classes like the super heavyweight class. They have expanded the weight classes they carry number of times over the years, but it's now been years since they've done so.
It's mainly a talent issue to have those weight classes. You'd need 30+ active fighters in a weight class in UFC to have a healthy rotation. And that's just within the organization. Outside the organization there has to also be a pool of athletes to bring in routinely. Realistically there's not enough fighters to support the missing weight classes.
Famously, Women's 145 pound class had been under jeopardy of getting cut for years, and only existed as Amanda Nunes was willing to defend both her 135 and 145 pound titles. With her retirement in 2023, the 145 pound class was dropped due to lack of talent.
